# Merge vectors in list based on matching names of elements

Tags: r, list, merge

I have a list that I want to merge:

```
path_list <- list(a = c("path1","path2","path3"), b= c("path4","path5"), c= c("path6","path7"), d = c("path8","path9","path10"))

path_list
$a
[1] "path1" "path2" "path3"

$b
[1] "path4" "path5"

$c
[1] "path6" "path7"

$d
[1] "path8"  "path9"  "path10"
```

I want to merge the elements in them based on the `data.frame` below:

```
ID.list <- data.frame(Id1 = c("a","b", "c","d"), Id2 = c("c","d","a","b"))

Id1 Id2
a   c
b   d
```

So that `a-c` merge together as do `b-d`, giving the name of `ID.list$ID2`.

```
result
$c
[1] "path1" "path2" "path3" "path6" "path7"

$d
[1] "path4" "path5" "path8"  "path9"  "path10"
```

Is this possible? I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515390/r-combine-a-list-of-vectors-into-a-single-vector) but my real data has 40 `Ids` so couldn't figure out how to do it.

EDIT:

**Note that the merge between `a-c` will be the same as `c-a` (same goes for `b-d`)**. How would I go about deleting the duplicates even though they have different names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can loop through the sequence of rows of 'ID.list', subset the elements of 'ID.list', use that as index to get the 'path_list' elements and `unlist` it.

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(ID.list)), function(i)  
     unlist(path_list[as.character(unlist(ID.list[i,]))], use.names=FALSE))
```

---

Or another option is `split` by row and then subset it

```
lapply(split(as.matrix(ID.list), row(ID.list)), function(x) 
                              unlist(path_list[x], use.names = FALSE))
```

#### Update

If there are elements in 'ID.list' in reverse, perhaps this should work

```
ID.list2 <- as.data.frame(unique(t(apply(ID.list, 1, sort))), 
              stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
lst <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(ID.list2)), function(i)  
    unlist(path_list[as.character(unlist(ID.list2[i,]))], use.names=FALSE))
names(lst) <- ID.list2[,2]
```

Comment: I apologize, it seems I mistook OP's aim

Comment: @bouncyball  It's okay, I was also misleaded by the post

Comment: This works to a certain extent. The list they create don't have the names of what is in column `ID.list$Id2`. Is this possible?

Comment: @Bonono  You can set the names as `setNames(lapply(....,), as.character(ID.list[[2]]))`

Comment: Please see my edit - I realised that in the real data that `ID.list` is slightly different.

Comment: @Bonono  I guess the `setNames(lapply(...), unique(t(apply(ID.list, 1, sort)))[,2])` should work, right? after changing the 'ID.list' to `ID.list2 <- as.data.frame(unique(t(apply(ID.list, 1, sort))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`